# Please, How to use getxController with multi-step registration form while working with an external api in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Please, How to use getxController with multi-step registration form in flutter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get.put({Your Controller})` in your screens to reach same controller.